# Image in html email is not displaying

Tags: php, html

I have sent html mail in my application with php. One image is displaying in that. But one is not displaying. While inspecting I could find an !+ inside the link like http://*********.com/rese!+rvation/admin/vehicles/rollsroyceghost.png

this is my code

```
    $message  ='<html><body style="height:100%;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#9E9E9E;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;border:1px solid #d9a58b;padding:0px 20px;">';
    $message .= '<div style="width:auto;height:60px;border-bottom:1px solid #d9a58b;">';
    $message .= '<img style="width:20%;margin: 5px 40px;float:right;" src="http://********.com/reservation/images/limo-logo.png" />';
    $message .= '<h2 style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;width:80%;padding: 20px 0px;">Limo Booking Confirmation</h2>';
    $message .= '</div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:auto;">';
    $message .='<h2 style="text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;">Congratulations! Thank you for using On Call Limo Service.</h2>';
    $message .='<h3 style="text-align:center;padding:5px 0px;margin:0px;">Your Limo has been booked and the details are indicated below.</h3></div>';

    $message .='<div style="width:auto;background:#eee; padding:10px 20px; margin:20px 0px;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:auto;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:20px;">';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;padding:5px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;" >Customer Details</h3>';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">'.strip_tags($name).'</h3>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;">Your Customer ID :<strong>'.strip_tags( $clientid).'</strong></p>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Email : '.strip_tags($email).'</p>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Phone : '.strip_tags($phone).'</p></div>';

    $message .='<div style="width:auto;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;padding:20px 0px;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">Pick up Address</h3>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">DATE :'.strip_tags($date).' | TIME :'.strip_tags($time).'</p>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">'.strip_tags($pick).'</p></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;float:right;">';
    if($type!='Hourly Hire'){
       $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">Drop In Address</h3>';
       $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;"></p>';
       $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">'.strip_tags($drop).'</p>';
    } else{
       $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;"></h3>';
       $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;"></p>';
       $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;"></p>';
   }     

    $message .='</div></div><div style="width:auto;padding:20px 0px;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">Your Vehicle</h3>';
    $message .='<img style="width:100px; height:50px; display:inline;" src="http://*********.com/reservation/admin/vehicles/'.$image.'" />';
    $message .='</div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;float:right;">';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">Vehicle details</h3>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">NO : '.strip_tags($vno).'</p>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Name: '.strip_tags($vname).'</p>';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;"></p></div></div></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:auto;padding:20px 20px;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:auto; padding:0px 20px;">';
    $message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">Fare Details</h3>';
    $message .='<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Booking charge : </p></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;float:right;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;font-weight:bold;">'.strip_tags($amount).'</p></div></div>';
    $message .='<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Service Charge: </p></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;float:right;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;font-weight:bold;">'.strip_tags($charge).'</p></div></div>';
    $message .='<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;">Total Fare :</p></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:50%;float:right;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;"> '.strip_tags($tot).'AED *</p></div></div>';
    $message .='<div style="width:auto;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">';
    $message .='<p style="color:#000;margin:10px 0px;font-weight:bold;">*Payment Gateway charges as applicable.</p></div></div></div>';
    $message .='<div style="margin:20px 0px;">'; 
    $message .='<p style="margin:3px 0px;">*For any further assistance, please contact us at 24*7 Hrs.</p>';
    $message .='<p style="margin:3px 0px;">*Customer Support at <strong>800 55033</strong> or mail us at care@***********.com</p></div>';        
    $message .='<div style="width:auto;height:20px;border-top:1px solid #d9a58b;padding: 15px 0px 20px 0px;">';
    $message .='<a href="http://****************.com" target="_blank" style="color:#9E9E9E;display:inline;">www.oncall-limo.com</a>';
    $message .='<span style="display:inline;float:right;"><a href="http://*********.com/reservation" target="_blank" style="color:#9E9E9E;font-weight:bold;">Book another Limo</a></span></div>';
    $message .='</div></html>';
    $message = html_entity_decode($message);

      if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            header('location:admin/booking.php');
      } else{
           echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
      }
```

There are some variables which is getting from database. vehicle name also getting from db($image).
How can I get the image?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the `!+` in the link

Comment: I didn't put anything like that. but when it reached in mail this symbols came

Comment: how you create the html script for mail content.

Comment: $message  ='<html><body style="height:100%;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#9E9E9E;">';    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)

Comment: $message .='</div></div><div style="width:auto;padding:20px 0px;">';
$message .='<div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">';
$message .='<h3 style="color:#000;margin:0px;">Your Vehicle</h3>';
$message .='<img style="width:100px; height:50px; display:inline;" src="http://*********.com/reservation/admin/vehicles/'.$image.'" />';
$message .='</div>';  where $image is vehicle name getting from db.

Comment: Do not write code in comments. Put it in the body of the question.

Comment: Have you enabled images on your email client? Most have it disabled, due to pixel-tracking and other tracking techniques.

Comment: on image is displaying. in this link http://********.com/reservation/images/limo-logo.png

Comment: @Ranju What? I don't understand...

Comment: there are two images in my html email. in thatv one is displaying. another is not displaying.